# Vertical black bars in nav buttons

Tags: html, nav

Taking an ultra-basic HTML class and just need to submit this project so I don't fail the class. On my simply ugly-ass menu I get a vertical black bar inside my buttons to the left of the text on every button except "Home". Thank you for your help stay cool B)
My nav code is:

```
<style>
    nav ul {list-style-type :none;
            margin : 0 25% 0 25%;}
    nav ul li {
            float : center;
    }
article {clear : left;}
nav ul li {
        float : left;
        margin-right : 1em;
        margin-bottom : 1em;
        text-align:center;
}
nav ul li a {
        text-align:center;
        padding : 0.25em .5em;
        text-decoration : bold;
        background-color : tan;
        color : black;
        border : 1px solid black;
        border-top-left-radius :  0em 0em;
        border-top-right-radius : 0em 0em;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Fish Stories</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</li>
            <li><a href="teenfishes.html">Teen Fisherman</li>
            <li><a href="alienfish.html">Alien Fish</li>
            <li><a href="talltale.html">Jean Sot</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Learn to use an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/). It will tell you where your mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your HTML code structure as below.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="teenfishes.html">Teen Fisherman</a></li>
    <li><a href="alienfish.html">Alien Fish</a></li>
    <li><a href="talltale.html">Jean Sot</a></li>
</ul>
```